# BigQuery combine tables based on closest timerstamp and matching value

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables and for each row of table **numberTwo** I need to get the **hint** in table **numberOne** that has the same **cod** value and between those, the one that has the **closest time** when comparing **time1** and **time2**.

To make it easier to understand what I need to do is:

**Table numberOne:**

```
|  id |  cod  |   hint  |           time1         |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  ABC  |    V    | 2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC |
|  2  |  ABC  |    W    | 2016-11-03 12:00:00 UTC |
|  3  |  CDE  |    X    | 2016-11-03 19:00:00 UTC |
|  4  |  CDE  |    Y    | 2016-11-03 19:30:00 UTC |
|  5  |  EFG  |    Z    | 2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC |
```

**Table numberTwo**

```
|  id |  cod  |   value  |         time2           |
----------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  ABC  |   xyz2   | 2016-11-03 18:20:00 UTC |
|  2  |  ABC  |   h323   | 2016-11-03 11:30:00 UTC |
|  3  |  ABC  |   rewq   | 2016-11-03 09:00:00 UTC |
|  4  |  CDE  |   abce   | 2016-11-03 19:10:00 UTC |
```

So, for **row #1** of table **numberTwo** I would get all rows in table **numberOne** with **cod: ABC**

```
|  1  |  ABC  |    V    | 2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC |
|  2  |  ABC  |    W    | 2016-11-03 12:00:00 UTC |
```

And between those I would get the one with the closest timestamp from **time2**:

```
|  1  |  ABC  |    V    | 2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC |
```

After processing every row I would have a table like this:

**Desired Table**

```
|  id |  cod  |   hint  |   value  |         time2           |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  ABC  |    V    |   xyz2   | 2016-11-03 18:20:00 UTC |
|  2  |  ABC  |    W    |   h323   | 2016-11-03 11:30:00 UTC |
|  3  |  ABC  |    W    |   rewq   | 2016-11-03 09:00:00 UTC |
|  4  |  CDE  |    X    |   abce   | 2016-11-03 19:10:00 UTC |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for BigQuery Standard SQL - try below

you can uncomment commented block with sample data for quick testing

```
WITH 
/*    
TableNumberOne AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'V' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'W' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 12:00:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'CDE' AS cod, 'X' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 19:00:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'CDE' AS cod, 'Y' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 19:30:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS id, 'EFG' AS cod, 'Z' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC' AS time1 
),
TableNumberTwo AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'xyz2' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 18:20:00 UTC' AS time2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'h323' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 11:30:00 UTC' AS time2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'rewq' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 09:00:00 UTC' AS time2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'CDE' AS cod, 'abce' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 19:10:00 UTC' AS time2 
),
*/
tempTable AS (
  SELECT 
    t2.id, t2.cod, t2.value, t2.time2, t1.hint, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.id, t2.cod, t2.value 
                      ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(t2.time2, t1.time1, SECOND))) AS win
  FROM TableNumberTwo AS t2
  JOIN TableNumberOne AS t1
  ON t1.cod = t2.cod
)
SELECT id, cod, hint, value, time2
FROM tempTable
WHERE win = 1
```

Comment: Should I want to keep the rows that are not matched, How would I do that? (The hint would be NULL for those....)

Comment: you would use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN

Comment: Oh ok, now I'm starting to understand haha. Thank you very much for being so helpful, you are the best.

Comment: Is there any other way? Because if I use left join (including in the other question) the billing tier from 68 goes to basically infinite (4628414464 or higher required.) and just keeps going up making it impossible to run the query.

Comment: wow, no good. even 68 is big enough. i will think. will get back later tonight.

Comment: see my second answer to address your comments. i didnt want to dirt my original answer so added new one

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way? Because if I use left join (including in the
>   other question) the billing tier from 68 goes to basically infinite
>   (4628414464 or higher required.) and just keeps going up making it
>   impossible to run the query

There are few areas I see to play with

1 - `ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(t2.time2, t1.time1, SECOND))` - this function is running for all permutation in join. You might want to experiment with converting respective time fields into seconds for each table in separate sub-select and than use it instead of original tables - so you will then just need to do something like `ABS(t2.time2inSeconds - t1.time1inSeconds)`

2 - Use of `ROW_NUMBER()` is another potential source of expenses - see below query where I tried to totally re-write logic  - but it is quite blind attempt as I cannot test it and see if this actually fix or improve stuff or not. Would be great if you can try and let know result (billing tier)

```
WITH 
/*    
TableNumberOne AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'V' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'W' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 12:00:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'CDE' AS cod, 'X' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 19:00:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'CDE' AS cod, 'Y' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 19:30:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS id, 'EFG' AS cod, 'Z' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC' AS time1 
),
TableNumberTwo AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'xyz2' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 18:20:00 UTC' AS time2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'h323' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 11:30:00 UTC' AS time2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'rewq' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 09:00:00 UTC' AS time2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'CDE' AS cod, 'abce' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 19:10:00 UTC' AS time2 
),
*/
tempTable1 AS (
  SELECT 
    t2.id, t2.cod, t2.value, 
    MIN(ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(t2.time2, t1.time1, SECOND))) AS delta 
  FROM TableNumberTwo AS t2
  JOIN TableNumberOne AS t1
  ON t1.cod = t2.cod
  GROUP BY t2.id, t2.cod, t2.value
),
tempTable2 AS (
  SELECT a.id, a.cod, a.value, a.time2, b.delta
  FROM TableNumberTwo AS a 
  JOIN tempTable1 AS b 
  ON a.id = b.id AND a.cod = b.cod AND a.value = b.value
)
SELECT a.id, a.cod, t1.hint, a.value, a.time2
FROM tempTable2 AS a
JOIN TableNumberOne AS t1
ON t1.cod = a.cod AND ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(a.time2, t1.time1, SECOND)) = delta
```

Note: above query still should be complete because it can return few matching rows from tableOne that are equally close to respective row in tableTwo. But for now  - it is just to verify that cost issue is fixed or improved at least

3 - Btw, it also can be your skewed data, etc.