# BigQuery - Combine three tables based on matching value or timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

Similar to question [BigQuery combine tables based on closest timerstamp and matching value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413094/bigquery-combine-tables-based-on-closest-timerstamp-and-matching-value)

I have three tables and for each row of table **numberTwo** I need to get the **hint** in table **numberOne** that has the same **cod** value and between those, the one that has the **closest time** when comparing **time1** and **time2**. If **cod** is not presented in table **numberOne** it tries to get the **hint** matching the **cod** in table **numberThree**

To make it easier to understand what I need to do is:

**Table numberOne:**

```
|  id |  cod  |   hint  |           time1         |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  ABC  |    V    | 2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC |
|  2  |  ABC  |    W    | 2016-11-03 12:00:00 UTC |
|  3  |  CDE  |    X    | 2016-11-03 19:00:00 UTC |
|  4  |  CDE  |    Y    | 2016-11-03 19:30:00 UTC |
|  5  |  EFG  |    Z    | 2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC |
```

**Table numberTwo**

```
|  id |  cod  |   value  |         time2           |
----------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  ABC  |   xyz2   | 2016-11-03 18:20:00 UTC |
|  2  |  FHK  |   h323   | 2016-11-03 11:30:00 UTC |
|  3  |  ABC  |   rewq   | 2016-11-03 09:00:00 UTC |
|  4  |  IJK  |   abce   | 2016-11-03 19:10:00 UTC |
```

**Table numberThree**

```
|  id |  cod  |   hint   |
--------------------------
|  1  |  FHK  |   tes1   |
|  2  |  IJK  |   tes2   |
|  3  |  MNK  |   tes3   |
|  4  |  MOP  |   tes4   |
```

So, for **row #1** of table **numberTwo** I would get all rows in table **numberOne** with **cod: ABC**

```
|  1  |  ABC  |    V    | 2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC |
|  2  |  ABC  |    W    | 2016-11-03 12:00:00 UTC |
```

And between those I would get the one with the closest timestamp from **time2**:

```
|  1  |  ABC  |    V    | 2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC |
```

If the **cod** is not presented in table **numberOne** it matches against table **numberThree**. The codes in **numberOne** and **numberThree** are unique. So there is no case where the same code will be presented in both tables. So it could try to match table **numberThree** first.

After processing every row I would have a table like this:

**Desired Table**

```
|  id |  cod  |   hint  |   value  |         time2           |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  ABC  |    V    |   xyz2   | 2016-11-03 18:20:00 UTC |
|  2  |  FHK  |   tes1  |   h323   |                         |
|  3  |  ABC  |    W    |   rewq   | 2016-11-03 09:00:00 UTC |
|  4  |  IJK  |   tes2  |   abce   |                         |
```

Comment: what is schema for numberThree? and what is expected output schema? + simple example please!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant i've updated the question.

Comment: did this work ?

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40941368/5221944  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
WITH 
/*
TableNumberOne AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'V' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'W' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 12:00:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'CDE' AS cod, 'X' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 19:00:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'CDE' AS cod, 'Y' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 19:30:00 UTC' AS time1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS id, 'EFG' AS cod, 'Z' AS hint, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 18:00:00 UTC' AS time1 
),
TableNumberTwo AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'xyz2' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 18:20:00 UTC' AS time2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'FHK' AS cod, 'h323' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 11:30:00 UTC' AS time2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'ABC' AS cod, 'rewq' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 09:00:00 UTC' AS time2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'IJK' AS cod, 'abce' AS value, TIMESTAMP '2016-11-03 19:10:00 UTC' AS time2 
),
TableNumberThree AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'FHK' AS cod, 'test1' AS hint UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'IJK' AS cod, 'test2' AS hint UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'MNK' AS cod, 'test3' AS hint UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, 'MOP' AS cod, 'test4' AS hint 
),
*/
tempTable AS (
  SELECT 
    t2.id, t2.cod, t2.value, t2.time2, t1.hint, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.id, t2.cod, t2.value 
                      ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(t2.time2, t1.time1, SECOND))) AS win
  FROM TableNumberTwo AS t2
  LEFT JOIN TableNumberOne AS t1
  ON t1.cod = t2.cod
)
SELECT 
  t1.id, t1.cod, IFNULL(t1.hint, t2.hint) AS hint, value, 
  IF(t1.hint IS NULL, NULL, time2) as time2
FROM tempTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN TableNumberThree AS t2
ON t1.cod = t2.cod AND t1.hint IS NULL
WHERE win = 1
```